# Sweave Error "found no \\citation commands"

Tags: r, sweave

I am using Sweave to build a pdf and things were running fine. I recently reinstalled Miktex and Texnic Centre. Even when building a basic document such as  the RNW below, I am getting the error "... found no \citation commands while reading name.aux file...found no \bibdata command while reading name.aux file...found no \bibstyle command while reading name.aux file"

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\pagebreak


\end{document}
```

Setting concordance = FALSE results in the same error. There are no references/citations in the document - expectedly, Texnic Centre encounters no errors in building a similar document.

Can anyone help me here please?

Thank you

Comment: You haven't given us much to work with.  What did you do to build that?  Did you have .aux files around from a previous build?